# spring boot - postgresql transactions

Tags: spring, postgresql, transactions

I have the following setup:
- a spring boot application makes a post request to insert an object using hibernate into a postgresql table TableA;
- that certain postgresql table has a trigger that on certain conditions triggers a function that does an insert into a TableB;
- TableB has 2 triggers: the first one uses listen/notify function to send notifications on websocket after insert on TableB and the second one uses a function to insert into TableC

The problem: If the first insert the client does in TableA is successfully, he receives 200 Code, but down the road there are possibly another 2 inserts. 
If a problems arises during either of the following inserts, the client sees 200 Code, but missed important data.
My logic says this has to be wrapped into a transaction-style entity of all-or-nothing but how do i do that ?

Kind Regards,

EDIT1: I just made a test, i annotated the first post request method with @Transactional and during the following inserts, if it encounters any error and any of the insert is not executed, the client is returned 500 error code. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: can you show error or something

Answer (score 0):

Annonate the first request method with @Transactional and control all possible errors, even by using try and catch blocks.

You should also define which errors your code is going to return, not all of them will be caused by the server, when you should be returning a 5XX error, but also by the client (e.g. sending wrong or unexpected parameters) and you should probably return 4XX code.